# Move search matches to the front of the line

Tags: vim

I have following snippets in a file

```
-- fixed prefix 999-12345678-99 fixed postfix
-- fixed prefix 999-12345678-99 fixed postfix
-- fixed prefix 999-12345678-99 fixed postfix
```

and need to convert this to

```
999-12345678-99 -- fixed prefix fixed postfix
999-12345678-99 -- fixed prefix fixed postfix
999-12345678-99 -- fixed prefix fixed postfix
```

Currently I'm using

- `%norm f9dtf0P`
- or `%s/\v(.{-})([-,0-9]{15} )/\2\1`

which works but I'd like to use a workflow where

- I create a search pattern matching just the part I'd like to move `/\v[-,0-9]{15}`
- globally act on that match without altering my search pattern to move it to the front of the line *(only one match per line)*

but I can't get my head around it on how to do that

**Edit**

I'm not looking for a way to insert my search pattern into a command, that part is covered but I'm looking for a way to not alter the search pattern at all.

A global command perhaps but I have no idea what command to execute for each line.

Comment: Would it suffice to save the current search pattern and then restore it after the command runs?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're after, but you could do this:

```
:g/\v[-,0-9]{15}\ /normal gnlx0P
```

That is, globally

1. Search for the pattern
2. Visually select "next match" with `gn` (from vim 7.4)
3. Cut, go to the beginning of the line and paste `x0P`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<c-r>/` to insert that last search into the command. From this you can then create a mapping that does your substitute automatically.

```
nnoremap <leader>s :%s/\v(.{-})(<C-R>/ )/\2\1<CR>
```

The usage would be search for something (in very magic mode (`\v`)). Then hit `<leader>s` to move that match to the beginning of the line.

(If the search is not a very magic regex then the regex might be interpreted improperly.)

Relevant help togic is `:h <c-r>`

Comment: I know that but that's not what I'm looking for. I'll edit the question to make that clear, sorry about the confusion.